# How does information gets stored into EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom, memory

How does information gets physically written to an Arduino Uno EEPROM ? Is each bit of information in fact a small condensator which fills and retains its charge even when the Arduino is powered down ? Are there little microscopic doors which open/close when bits get set to 1 in the EEPROM ? How does it work ?

Comment: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/flash-memory.htm

Comment: I'm migrating this question to Electronics Stack Exchange because it is very broad. You could equally ask about Microchip processors, or any Atmel processor. Be warned that they may want the question to show that you have done some research yourself, and that the research (which you should cite) didn't fully answer your question.

Comment: Heard of a MOSFET? It's basically storing a voltage value in a MOSFET that is designed to retain its state for a long time

Comment: Modern EEPROMs are made with floating gate FETs.  The gate is insulated, so retains whatever charge was last put on it.  The charge is added and removed by harnessing quantum tunneling.  No really.  However, for all I know arduinos move pebbles around between buckets to keep track of bits.

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle differences in technology and management of the technology between different non-volatile memory.  In general these devices use a [floating gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Floating-gate_transistor):

[image]

And are set using electricity.  [Some are cleared using ultra violet radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM) and [others are cleared with electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM).